# Mac OS X - fire up Apache/Mysql without prompting for password

Tags: xampp

I am running XAMPP which comes with a little "XAMPP Control" app that lets me start and stop Apache and MySQL by clicking a button. When I do that, I'm prompted by Lion for my admin password. Is there a way to skip this step? (On Windows, this is sort of like me asking "how can I run the XAMPP Control program in administrator mode?" --not sure if there's an analog for Mac.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

Mac OSX asks you for your password because *XAMPP* is trying to run the *nix command `[sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)`. This can be overcome by one of two ways:

a. Allow **ALL** `sudo` commands to be run without a password.

b. Allow **ONLY** the *XAMPP* command to be run with no password.

## Solution

To use one of these solutions, do the following:

1. Open *Terminal.app* (I like to hit <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then type "Terminal.app", then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Run `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`.
3. Append the following text to the file, where username is your **short username** (type `whoami` into the terminal to get it):

   - For option **a**:

   `%username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD`

   - For option **b**:

   `%username ALL= NOPASSWD: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp`
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, and save when prompted.

Note that on OSX Mavricks, you may have to add a <kbd>%</kbd> sign before the username (in `/etc/sudoers`).

Comment: FYI I added this: "username ALL= NOPASSWD: /Applications/XAMPP/XAMPP\ Control.app"

Comment: For `etc/sudoer` noobs, like me, be careful **not** to edit `sudoers` file using your favorite text editor (just made this mistake … spent last hour trying to fix). The `sudoer` file has this commented message at the top: **This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root (i.e., `$ sudo visudo`). Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors that prevent sudo from running.**

Comment: Use the visudo command. It will check the file syntax before 'commiting' it.

Answer (score 8):

The thread [Starting Xampp Control Panel without password](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=160506) lists two possible solutions :

1. Write scripts that start and stop XAMPP, specifying the password in the scripts.
   The two scripts are included in the thread.
2. Edit the `/etc/sudoers` file, configuring that `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start` doesn't need a password.

Comment: Using the Script and Exporting it as a .App was the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## macOS High Sierra

In High Sierra I couldn't get the new control app **manager-osx** working without entering password, even when adding it in sudoers.

But you can run xampp from command line to start and stop xampp (or only apache) without password, if you add it to the sudoers file.

But: The solutions above made problems for me, so here what I did:

**Do not** edit `/etc/sudoers/` file, many things can go wrong! If you really want, use `sudo visudo`
macOS also will not allow to use `vim sudoers` (you cannot save), at least with activated SIP.

### Better approach

Create a new file in the directory `/etc/sudoers.d`. You need root rights to create the file.
Name the file like your username (for example). No extension needed.
Filename doesn't really matter, but it must not cotain a `~` at end or a dot (`.`) at beginning.

In this new file create only the needed entries, but **DON'T** add a `%` in front of your username. This didn't work for me and every call of `sudo` took a long time before asking the password.

#### Content of the new file:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp
```

Now you can run

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start
```

in a Termin to start xampp and you don't have to enter your password.

### If something goes wrong

Delete all your entries in the sudoers or the new file, or comment them with double `##` so sudo will ignore them.
Try this, if file is completely broken: https://astrails.com/blog/2009/09/29/how-to-fix-a-hosed-etc-sudoers-file-on-mac-osx
If nothing else works, reboot to single user mode and repair the file. There should also be a backup in `/etc` called `sudoers~orig`.